# MySQL doesn't use the options in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, centos, virtual-machine, database-replication

I use a virtual machine CentOS on work. I was able to work with it's MySQL 5.6 without trouble, but now this virtual machine was cloned (literally cloned) to create another one on the same server. Since then, the original virtual machine does not use the options defined on [mysqld] from /etc/my.cnf file. I'm trying to change the server-id option of the machines so I can set DB replication on them, but the problem persists on both machines (and replication can't be set with server-id=0, which is the default value that it's assuming).

OBS: Before the machine was cloned, I had no problems at all and succeeded to create replication between this original VM and another computer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Permissions? Are you reading the correct `my.cnf`?

Comment: This is more of a system administration than a programming-related question so it’s off-topic for StackOverflow.
You’d have a much better chance of getting useful answers at [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).
Adding a tag for CentOS would also help.